# Generic Class constructor get parent, set value in parent?

Tags: c#, generics

I am creating a huge set of classes, where I have extended functionality of these classes with a generic class constructor.

Now I want to move all domain specific logic into this generic constructor, however I am a little stuck how do I get the caller-object when methods inside the "extension" are called. Equal to "this" when methods are called within parent classes them self.

Also how can I set the Id in parent when called from extension?  `long id` is the value I want to be able to change from generically called methods. This always exist as long in any class extended with the DomainLogic constructor.

Example:

```
public class TestUser : DomainLogic<TestUser>
{
    public TestUser(string Name)
    {
        this.Id = 0;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Id;
    }
}

public class DomainLogic<T> where T : class
{
    public void Save()
    {
        //
        // Code that stores the object in repository here.
        // How do i get the calling object?
        // Repo<T>.Save(calling object)
        //
        // Otherwise i have to use:
        //
        // public void Save(T entity)
        // {
        //     if(entity.GetHashCode() == 0)
        //     { 
        //         // entity.Id = Repo<T>.Next(); // How can i set a parent value from generic called method?
        //
        //         // More logic we apply when this is considered a newly saved object.
        //     }
        //     else
        //     {
        //         // More logic we apply when this is considered a modified object.
        //     }
        //
        //     Repo<T>.Save(entity);
        // }
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also just figured that I should rather extend the class with an abstract class.

Comment: I think you don't really want to do this: `DomainLogic` wants to know all sorts of things about it's own children ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [the `Id` property] always exist as long in any class extended with the DomainLogic constructor

Then put the `Id` property in the `DomainLogic` class if you want to be able to access it from `DomainLogic<T>.Save()`.

Also, you can just use `this` in `DomainLogic<T>.Save()`.